# Braking of Motors

Tags: current, dc, dc-motor, induction-motor

Is an induction motor delivering or drawing mechanical power in the braking region?

.[image]

according to the torque slip curve of an Induction motor,torque is positive and the motor continue to rotate in the same direction.
So is the motor still delivering mechanical power?

Comment: Slip is higher than 1 in the breaking region, which means the anchor rotates in *opposite direction* from the stator. Not sure why you mention "motor continue to rotate in the same direction". In breaking region the motor will draw mechanical power, which is pretty much what breaking is all about.

Comment: Am i wrong,As soon as the stator supply is changed,RMF moves in the opposite direction to the rotor,(rotor still continuing in the same direction ),which makes slip greater than 1.

Comment: Remember the rotor has mass of its own and thus kinetic energy.

Comment: The torque is positive - that is, in the same sense as the exciting AC. However as you are left of f=0, that is in the opposite direction to the actual rotation so the mechanical power delivered subtracts from the rotational energy.

Answer (score 1):

The situation that you are describing is instantaneously reversing the phase sequence of the power supplied to the motor while it is running. That is commonly known as "plugging." The motor is delivering positive torque from the point of view of the motor, but the torque is negative with respect to the rotation of the load. The motor is absorbing mechanical power from the load. That mechanical power is converted to electrical power in the rotor, but the rotor is absorbing the power, not returning it to the source. In addition, both the stator and rotor are dissipating power from the source.